# How does a "Super Kiss" work?

Tags: superman, powers

I just watched **Superman II** with my little nephew. At the end of film Clark basically removes over a week's worth of knowledge from Lois's mind (including his identity as Superman) by kissing her.

My nephew *totally bought* that Clark can "super kiss" her, but he asked *how* it might be possible, which got me to thinking;

- Is it a normal physical touch/sensory sensation, amplified to *beyond* human levels which then manipulates human physiology?
- Is it Superman extending some form of control over bio-electric energy via his aura?
- Is it a form of tactile telepathy?

All of which we've seen in the comics before or since. But which (if any) of these was it supposed to be. Or was it something else entirely?

[image]

Comment: Another very well researched question, but not one that's obviously answerable. You seem to have taken a pretty straightforward question (*"How was the Super kiss in S2 supposed to work"*) and dramatically complicated it. Honestly if I were you, I'd delete every word below "*"...tactile telepathy?"*

Comment: @Valorum noted. I may do that, but honestly... it seems as though the answer could go anyway. A lot of people wouldn't be familiar with the Super kiss itself, let alone the little detailed examples of Clark being able to apply his canon powersin different ways. You know me, V; I like to provide as much detail and analysis as possible to increase possibility of a viable answer in return.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that 99% of users are more familiar with the movie kiss (a question which, by the way is answerable) than anything from the comics.

Comment: Since your Q was closed/deleted, I've taken the liberty of editing it and getting it undeleted into a more suitable and appropriate form. You might want to consider recycling some of the research you did into a self-answer.

Comment: @Valorum Sorry dude; Covid 19 issues have been keeping me busy, hence the late response. I was fine with it being closed, because editing it would have taken some time. That being said, I gave all that detail _precisely_ because I was hoping to _Avoid_ answers like the one below.  Again, we **do** have precedence for a Super Kiss, but without the aforementioned data, its **highly speculative** as to _what_ the ability is exactly and _how_ it may work.

Comment: Which is great. Add all that missing info into a self-answer if you feel it'll answer the question. There's a good on-topic question now and a canonical answer (from the script) but if you think that adding extra things from earlier and later comics will build on that, go for it!

Answer (score -1):

This is addressed (albeit unsatisfactorily) in the [shooting script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/superman_II_shoot.txt). The kiss is described as being ***magical** in nature*.

> [MOVE IN TO VERY TIGHT TWO SHOT:   They look into each other's eyes.
> He takes off his glasses.]
>
> **CLARK** (almost a whisper)
> *I don't know what to say. . .*
>
> **LOIS** (his words to her when he came out of the Restructuring Chamber)
> *Say you love me.*
>
> [He takes her face in his hand and pulls her toward him. Though they have made love when he was briefly a mortal,
> this is the first and only time we have seen Superman kiss her.]
> [IN
> C.U., **it is a profound, lyrical, passionate kiss -- it is indeed
> magical.**]
>
> [When at last he releases her, she moves back, opening her eyes,
> blinking as if she had just awakened from a dream.]
>
> [PULL BACK AND WIDEN: as she shakes her head, like somebody who has
> had a dizzy spell. CLARK puts his glasses back on.]

It's described in the DVD audio commentary as a "new power" without any further explanation. Again, magic ('fairytale') is referenced.

> **Pierre Spengler:** *This is a new power but we discussed it with the comic book wizards and they... it makes sense. It's actually almost like a fairytale, which I just thought about. It's like Prince Charming [when he] wakes Sleeping Beauty. ... And yes, it's basically like it's the end of the fairytale for her with him. There was a moment of fairytale there.*

We may also note that [actual factual magic does exist](https://youtu.be/NMUeFT7iqSQ?t=89) in this series of Superman films and that it won't be the last time we see magic [being used to affect someone's mind](https://youtu.be/7gcEYjYYTcw?t=62).

---

And as you pointed out in the *[original](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/226892/revisions)* version of this question, super-kissing is a power that has been seen in the source comics. Evidently it's just something that Superman can do.

[image]

Comment: I have to disagree with this **explicitly** because it is _overtly stated_ that Superman's powers **are NOT MAGICAL in nature!** To your credit though, this was the *exact panel**  (or one of them, at least,)  I used to showcase a "Super kiss" before; another was with Catwoman, and another with wonder woman.  The question was closed, then edited, removing those panels and details of how this _could_ be an extension of his bio-electric aura manipulation, _or_ of his tactile telekinesis. As to it being "magic" in any way, though... I believe that was more of an _allusion_ than explanation.

Comment: @Russhiro - You have to remember that Spengler knows next to nothing about Superman. His knowledge of the character largely comes from general tropes, a few half-remembered episodes of the radio show and his watching of the earlier film. He's not writing it from the perspective of a fan who would know that magic isn't something that Superman does. He refers to the event as magical, a fairytale, etc. because that's all well and good with him.